# How can we integrate LDAP (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) in our android application?

Tags: java, android

I am having trouble searching for any example regarding LDAP authentication in my android app. There are some github links available but I am not able to understand what are the things required for such task to be done. Plz help...
I want to know the steps required and any dependency or other things as I am new to all this. Hope android being open source helps.

Comment: You can use [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.ldap.com/unboundid-ldap-sdk-for-java)

Comment: plz can you tell me steps involved... I have downloaded the jar, integrated with my app and now I want to know what else is required.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample application available [here](https://github.com/weisserd/LDAP-Sync) you can give it a try.

The entities required for LDAP authentication are:

1. The host address of the LDAP server.
2. The port number of the LDAP server.
3. The Username to use to bind to the server.
4. The password to use to bind to the server.

Comment: it's working.... but next part where I searched for a test server and I got this http://www.forumsys.com/en/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/ The credentials and host and port name are available. So I made connection with this but I am not able to understand how use the query as there is no example for getting entities or adding. It's mentioned in the sample doc but not clear how to use it. Do we also need any server or framework to operate.